# Store sparse voxel trees in Geode or gemfire

Tags: gemfire, geode

Is it possible to store binary data in GEODE or Gemfire?
In particular, I would like to store binary structures of sparse voxel octrees and retrieve them using a 3D coordinate.

If yes,  is it possible to create a client in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much about voxel structures, I can't comment on the best way to do this. Geode/GemFire is designed to store binary data. With a C++ client, you should use Geode's [PDX serialization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/PDX+Serialization+Internals). If it's a simple matter of retrieving a structure given a known coordinate, Geode should work well.

Comment: thank you very much! Sorry, the site doesnt exist (or I dont have the permission to read it)
Actually for me it would be enough to be able to provide a custom hash (key), class methods for (de)serialization and a client to query data. I found an example for [geospatial coordinates on Gemfire](https://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/01/gemfire-part-2-catherine-johnson.html) and hope to be able to do similar stuff with geode and octrees.

Comment: FYI... Fixed the link

Comment: thank you very much! From the first look I think this is a very promising approach for me. I guess it will take me some time to do some tests, so I mark your answer as "accepted". Thanks again!